# Can I use ground as neutral for a smart switch?

Tags: neutral, smart-switch

How bad an idea is it to use the ground from a switch loop light switch as the neutral (and ground) of a smart switch replacing the existing light switch?

Comment: The fact that it's in your house is completely irrelevant. It's also an ethical issue as it'll almost certainly still be there when you're gone.

Comment: @crip659 It appears the [Cync by GE](https://cyncsupport.gelighting.com/s/article/installing-cync-3-wire-switches?language=en_US#single-pole-3-wire) switches don't exclusively use ground, it uses the old way of bleeding some current through the load. The trick is it includes a screw-in lightbulb adapter with a resistor or some other circuit for the current to bypass a LED bulb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The practical implication of bootlegging (aka ground fault) is that any future damage/failure to the upstream grounding system would result in your smart switch energizing every "grounded" surface on the damaged portion of the home.  That includes high touch areas like faceplate screws and small appliances.  It might not be the full 120 VAC, but enough to do some damage.

Comment: Would the smart switch stop working if there was an grounding failure, like a canary in the coal mine?

Comment: That will happen anyway due to capacitive coupling in cables, but also if you have any grounded switch-mode power supply in your house, since there is a EMI filter capacitor between line and ground with a leakage current. They're [speced at up to 1 mA each](https://www.emea.lambda.tdk.com/uk/faq/question/105), so something drawing 100 mW to ground is going to be similar to a PC plugged in.

Answer (score 6):

There are a *few* smart switches that are **listed** to work with ground, not neutral. Those are the only ones you should be considering, unless you run new cable.